# Jquery on and hover selector based on class events not working

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

```
$(".typeofcontent").on({

    $(".typeofcontent").hover(function() {
        $(this).css("color", "#f9d58e");    
    });

}
```

This jQuery code does not execute the command to set the CSS color of an element with the classname of `typeofcontent`. Rather, it gives no console error code and simply does not execute. Would you mind elucidating me on what I am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the following code is needed. As `hover` event is binded by `hover()`, you don't need `on`.

```
$(".typeofcontent").hover(function() {
    $(this).css("color", "#f9d58e");
});
```

**Better Approach**

You don't need Javascript to do this. **Use CSS**

```
.typeofcontent:hover {
    color: #f9d58e;
}
```

Comment: I had to upvote when I saw the css. Nice catch and thinking outside the box :)

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(".typeofcontent").hover(function() {
        $(this).css("color", "#f9d58e");
    });
});
```

Comment: Please add some description in the answer

Answer (score 1):

You are passing in an object which is not a valid overload of [**on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/). If you wish to use `on()` pass in the **event**, **selector**(f*or delegation*), and **callback**

```
$(document).on('hover','.typeofcontent', function(){
    $(this).css("color", "#f9d58e");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The general syntax for jquery .on function is .on("event","child selectors","data","event handler").
2nd and 3rd arguments are optional so you can skip them.

In your case , "event"enter code here is passed as an object which is not valid .
So the correct use would be

```
$(".typeofcontent").on("hover", function() {
    $(this).css("color", "#f9d58e");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".typeofcontent").hover(function(){
    $(this).css("color", "#f9d58e");
});
```

the above code is enough to get the job done if you want to use hover function. However, if you want to do it with "on", the snippet is :

```
$(".typeofcontent").on('mouseover',function(){
    $(this).css("color", "#f9d58e");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".typeofcontent").hover(function() {
    $(this).css("color", "#f9d58e");
});
```

this will work